# On change event not fired with dynamically loaded data

Tags: javascript, events

I am dynamically loading data in the input type text and triggering alert if the value of the text box is changed. But my code does not seem to work. Please provide suggestions. 
visit this page for code: http://jsfiddle.net/NbGBj/103/

```
I want the alert to be shown when the page is loaded
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove your `"` around `document`

```
$("document").ready(function(){
...
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...
```

or use the shortcut

```
$(function(){
...
```

From the official documentation:

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> - $(document).ready(handler)
> - $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> - $(handler)
> ```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

But I guess what you want is the `keyup` event

```
$(function () {
    $("#upload").val("sample");
    $("#upload").keyup(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

And for better readability, you can use chaining

```
$(function () {
    $("#upload").val("sample").keyup(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BXNkq/

Answer (score 0):

You can just fire the change function directly after you set the value in the text box like this:

```
....
$("#upload").val("sample");
$("#upload").change();
....
```